# How to use dynamic links with a custom URL scheme?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

If I use https://appdomain.page.link/?link=myapp://appdomain.co%2Fwebview%2profile%2Fsignup%3Femail%3Dtestemail@test.com&ibi=co.myapp.mobile

the dynamic link is invalid because of the 'myapp://'. The API docs state I can only use https or http here, but when I do that, I cannot get it to open in iOS because iOS requires a custom URL scheme for universal links to work so I feel like i'm not understanding something here. I have tried adding 'https' to the list of schemes in my Info.plist but it still refuses to open the app, and goes straight to browser.

Setting the `ius` param in the dynamic link to 'myapp' does not work either.

How can I make this work?

Comment: This was actually fixed by someone, ill post the answer when i find more out about it (i know it had something to do with 'applinks' though).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify the `link` parameter without http if you want it to be cross platform, so you must make iOS handle `http`/`https` links instead, by using [applinks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/applinks). Make sure all the links you expect your app to handle (which do not start with a custom scheme) are defined under applinks.