# iOS universal links with 'https' scheme not opening app

Tags: deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I can get them to open just fine if I use a custom URL scheme, e.g. `myapp://app.co/path/to/content` but when I use `https://app.co/path/to/content` it just opens in the browser instead. Here is where my schemes are defined in my Info.plist:

```
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>co.myapp.mobile</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myapp</string>
            <string>co.myapp.mobile</string>
            <string>https</string>
            <string>http</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

If I remember correctly, this is the only place you need to define the custom schemes. If not, then that will be my problem.

P.S. Normally I would be fine to just use `myapp://` but I'm using firebase dynamic links which require the deep link to use http or https. That is a [separate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67902880/how-to-use-dynamic-links-with-a-custom-url-scheme).

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed using [applinks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/applinks). Make sure all the links you expect your app to handle (which do not start with a custom scheme) are defined under applinks.

Comment: Would you provide an example of the working solution?